# How to run part of exe file that is being reversed

Tags: ida, windows, exe, offset

I reverse exe file with IDA, there is a function (that is running some other function) that I  don't want to understand how it works, but I want to run it.

How can I run an exe file from a specific offset and give it parameters to some arguments?

Comment: Question too broad. Read these: https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/debugger/index.shtml and https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/debugging.shtml

Comment: @Biswapriyo I know how to debug program, that not what I want, I want to create a new exe file starting from spesific offset and set it parameters

Comment: Provide a hello world like example. It'll help to understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ida's [Appcall](https://hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/tutorials/debugging_appcall.pdf) functionality:

> Appcall is a mechanism to call functions inside the debugged program
>   from the debugger or your script as if it were a built-in function.
>   Such a mechanism can be used for debugging, fuzzing and testing
>   applications. Appcall mechanism highly depends on the type information
>   of the function to be called. For that reason it is necessary to have
>   a correct function prototype before doing an Appcall, otherwise
>   different or incorrect results may be returned.

I have an example of using Appcall or rolling your own on my blog [here](https://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2013/04/08/decrypting-dell-vworkspace-pit-files/).

Comment: thank you, your post is great! Can you show the code how do you invoke to `sub_41C91C` without use IDA ?with `CreateRemoteThread` by using `lpStartAddress` and how can you pass the file path as a argument to this function

Comment: @g319909.nwytg.coM at the bottom of my blog post is a download link which happens to include the source code (as mentioned in the article)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple, it must not do a lot of syscalls and interactions with the whole memory.

You may be looking for a Unicorn-based IDA plugin such as [this one](https://github.com/alexhude/uEmu) which can achieve emulation of not-too-dependent functions and provide you a view of registers and memory.

Otherwise, you may have to use Unicorns bindings outside of IDA, here are some [examples](http://www.unicorn-engine.org/docs/tutorial.html) and so you'll be able to emulate syscalls and all the stuff you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest using [LIEF](https://github.com/lief-project/LIEF/). It has a neat feature `add_exported_function` to add a function at an address as exported in a new file. You can have a look at this feature [here](https://lief.quarkslab.com/doc/latest/tutorials/08_elf_bin2lib.html)

Comment: Thank about your replay. I not sure I'm understand your offer. I have exe file with lot of function and I want to invoke to spesific function . Do you say that I can export this function ? How can I invoke to this function when I run the exe?  Thanks

Comment: If you go to the linked tutorial you'll see how you can use an exported function to call.